# Python neural network coding

Tags: python, csv, numpy, neural-network

I have a dermatology database of which the normalization is already done. It is a CSV file. I need to open the file and input into a numpy array. My database has 34 columns and about 350 rows. My neural network has 3 hidden layers. This is my present python code for the neural network. Can someone help me with the input in a numpy array/matrix? 
Thank you

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
#input x
X = np.array([  ])
#input y
y = np.array([]).T

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((34,26)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((26,18)) - 1
syn2 = 2*np.random.random((18,11)) - 1
syn3 = 2*np.random.random((11,6)) - 1
for j in xrange(350):
  l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
  l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l1,syn1))))
  l3 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l2,syn2))))
  l4 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l3,syn3))))
  l4_delta = (y - l4)*(l4*(1-l4))
  l3_delta = l4_delta.dot(syn3.T) * (l3 * (1-l3))
  l2_delta = l3_delta.dot(syn2.T) * (l2 * (1-l2))
  l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))
  syn3 += l1.T.dot(l4_delta)
  syn2 += l1.T.dot(l3_delta)
  syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
  syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the labels are in the last column,

```
X = np.array([[float(cell) for cell in row[:-1]] for row in csv.reader(open(csv_filename))])
Y = np.array([float(row[-1]) for row in csv.reader(open(csv_filename))])
```

I don't think you need to transpose `Y`, assuming it's one-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. This is the error i am getting                                                          Error: l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
ValueError: shapes (4,33) and (34,26) not aligned: 33 (dim 1) != 34 (dim 0)

Comment: Maybe your labels are in a separate file?  It sounds like you have 34 features so X should read every column, not just up to the last column.

Comment: Oh.. Can you please tell me how to fix it?  at X.... : l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))  and at y: l4_delta = (y - l4)*(l4*(1-l4))

Comment: I used transpose function and the error went.. Thank you for your help..  syn3 += np.dot(l3.transpose(),l4_delta)

Comment: Okay, sounds good.  You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I did so:

```
my_5_input_numbers.csv
0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,1
0.4,0.6,0.7,0.8,0
0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1
```

Used numpy:

```
data_common=np.genfromtxt('my_5_input_numbers.csv',delimiter=',')
"""
data_common=array([[ 0.3,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  1. ],
       [ 0.4,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ]])
data_common.shape=(3,5)       
"""

X_train=data_common[:,-1]#X_train.shape=(3,4)
y_train=data_common[0:4,-1]#y_train.shape=(3,)
y_train=y_train.reshape(3,1)
```